# Windows service fails to install for minor to major upgrade on Windows 8 in installshield

Tags: windows-8, installshield, major-upgrade

I have an installer of Minor Upgrade type. (Say MyAppMinor_v.msi)

I built another installer of same application of type Major Upgrade type (Say MyAppMajor_v+1.msi).

Both of these are built using  InstallShield 2014.

MyApp has a Windows system service (MyService.exe) running in background.
Also, MyApp has functionality to update itself from App UI; in which the application updates itself using following command:

```
msiexec.exe /i MyAppMajor_v+1.msi
```

This command is run from MyService.exe of MyAppMinor version.

After the update process is completed, the service MyService.exe for MyAppMajor version does not get installed.

It gives following error in Installer logs:

> MSI (s) (FC:2C) [10:17:54:387]: Product: MyAppMajor -- Error 1923.Service MyService failed to install.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.

I do have the admin privileges on the target machine.

This behavior is observed only on Windows 8/8.1.

On Windows 7 I do not get this error and MyService runs perfectly fine on MyAppMinor to MyAppMajor upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You may have admin on the box but it sounds with UAC you only have a standard user token.